# get a list of posts that a facebook page shares

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a crawler that collect posts from some public facebook pages. I found that when i do this query `graph.facebook.com/FBObjectID/feed?access_token=xxx`,
It will not return the posts that this page share. 
For Example, at this [page](https://www.facebook.com/Alfront), there is a share of this [post](https://www.facebook.com/Alfront/posts/858988217554404), but the facebook api don't return it.
How can i get this posts?

Answer (score 0):

Making a call to the post id directly: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/858988217554404&access_token=xxx` we get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

This indicates that you do not have enough permission to access this post. Now you might argue that this post is public and you can see it on facebook.com but when you access data via the API, the privacy rules differ to those on the site which determines whether or not you can access this data.

Simply put, if you cannot see the post when you call `graph.facebook.com/FBObjectID/feed?access_token=xxx` you cannot access it.